# Amazon EC2 Instance Connection Timeout after Access Key Rotation

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I recently rotated my AWS access key and now I can no longer ssh into my server. I'm getting a connection timeout error, and I'm not sure why.

I checked the server system logs and there don't appear to be any errors. I've looked at my security groups and SSH is allowed on 0.0.0.0/0 port: 22. Is there anything I forgot to do after rotating my security key? To rotate the key I clicked, 'make inactive', generated a new key and then deleted the inactive key.

Comment: Did you only change your key within ec2 control panel?

Comment: Are you talking about the Access Keys that you can change in the "Your Security Credentials" page? These are only used for programmatic access to the APIs, not for SSH access. Key Pairs are used for SSH access.

Comment: @DavidLevesque So you're saying that changing the access key should have had no effect on my accessing the server?

Comment: Yes, my understanding is that access keys have nothing to do with SSH access. Are you sure that you didn't change anything else?